# Print functionality throws an error saying access denied in IE 11 but works on Chrome with no issues using localhost

Tags: javascript, printing, internet-explorer-11

[Console log error for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CjW5.png)

This is my code:

```
    const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    const title = 'One-time payment - Billing';
    const printWin = window.open(title, title, `width=${width},height=${height},menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no`);
    if (!printWin) {
      return;
    }
    printWin.focus();
    printWin.document.title = title;
    printWin.document.write(`<title>${title}</title>`);
```

When I click on the print button it should open a window with print preview and then let the user print, which works perfectly on Chrome but not on IE 11. 
On IE 11 its throwing an error which says **Access is denied and opens a new window with 404 error**

Also I am running this code on Storybook localhost

Can someone help!

Comment: well IE11 does not support template literals so I would be expecting a different error

Comment: Please check the related folder whether you have permission to access the related js files? Here are some relate articles about the Access Denied error, you could refer to them: [article 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2623670/access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-f),

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in IE 11 and when I use `` instead of "" it gives me a error of invalid character because IE 11 does not support template literals.
Try change your code to this to see if you can manage it to work:

```
window.open(title, title, "width="+width+",height="+height+",menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no");
```

and:

```
printWin.document.write("<title>"+title+"</title>");
```

Comment: I just tried making those changes and checked but it still throws the same error and the window opened as an error 404 page. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the console log in the question, if that could help in any way

Comment: Whe you access the console (tapping F12) do you see any other error that can help us understand what is happening? The 404 error just makes sense if the code tries to access some page/resource that does not exist.

Comment: As I can see your code is minified in a bundle.js, it seems that there is a permission error, maybe you are developing in a company enviroment and some rule is blocking some code in your main.js

Comment: Yes you are right, but the same code is working on Chrome but not on IE 11. Please let me know if there is a workaround for this issue

Comment: You will have to debug your code, try to put a breakpoint before the error occurrs and see what is causing this. Try seeing the js file that is activating the error and try to understand what can be happening.